# Windows 7 Batch: Find /i

Tags: windows-7, find, cmd, replace

I have a windows batch file in Windows 7 which does something with find.

it starts with this:

```
find /i /c....
```

But it says something like

> find /i is no medium

or so. Then it just gives a list of every single file in the C:\ directory.

Is there any new replacement for Windows 7?

EDIT: If i hit `find /?` in cmd, it gives `find: /? there is no such file or directory`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably have the posix find command installed on your computer. Type:

```
where find.exe
```

To locate it. You probably can change the path environment variable on your system so the system32 directory will be first.

You could obtain something like the following :

```
> where find.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\find.exe
C:\Windows\System32\find.exe
```

In the above example, the first `find` executable is from Git system, in consequence commands like `find /I ...` (MS original) don't work anymore.

**Update:** First try to run the command with full path:

```
c:\windows\system32\find.exe /i "foo"
```

And see what happens.

Then compare the file to the same file in other windows 7 installation ( I don't have one right now). You can also look at the file property. Is it from microsoft?

Comment: Thanks, but the thing is that it is just installed in the Windows/System32/ directory. What is the problem than? I use the RTM from Technet

Comment: It work with the full path, so its ok. If i need to do that i need to do that.

Comment: helpful...answer!

Answer (score 0):

It appears from your example you're not encasing your search with quotes.
Find on its own or with /? will give you the command line options.
Find /i "SearchString" "MyFile" means search Myfile for SearchString but ignore case.