# Loop through stdout command line contents with "findstr" in Python and Windows 7

Tags: python, subprocess, windows-7-x64

I am writing a python script that uses Windows command line to send commands to a device, then reads the output iterates its contents:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen("adb logcat | findstr Test", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in proc.stdout:
    if "stopped" in line:
        print line
        print "Test Service finished \n"
        break
    else:
        print line
```

Unfortunately I get the following:

```
>>> 
/system/bin/sh: findstr: not found
output error: Broken pipe
```

it would work without the " | findstr Gps" but then the amount of output send to the pipe is too large and eventualy leads to memory incidents.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add a `proc.communicate()` before the `for line...` loop.

Comment: Thanks, the result is now:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/junk.py", line 20, in <module>
    for line in proc.stdout:
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Comment: `communicate()` returns a tuple `(stdoutdata, stderrdata)`, so change your `for` loop to read from the `stdoutdata` in that that instead of `proc.stdout` -- sorry I wasn't sure if that was needed, so I didn't mention it.

Comment: I am not sure how to change the "for line in proc.stdout" part. Should I also change the proc definition: "the proc = subprocess.Popen(mycommand, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)" ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the same response: >>> 
/system/bin/sh: findstr: not found
output error: Broken pipe

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work (not sure if the `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` is really necessary, although it shouldn't hurt):

```
proc = subprocess.Popen("adb logcat | findstr Test", stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE))
stdoutdata, stderrdata = proc.communicate()
for line in stdoutdata:
    if "stopped" in line:
        print line
        print "Test Service finished \n"
        break
    else:
        print line
```

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the same response: >>> /system/bin/sh: findstr: not found output error: Broken pipe. Could this be smth non python related? I mean could it be the case that popen fails to submit the cmd command because it cannot find findstr?

Comment: I think I know what the problem is: `findstr` is not a filter -- it doesn't read from stdin so can't be used with a pipe. You need to use the `find` command instead, which will read from stdin if no file name is specified. It does do regular expression and the text to search for has to enclosed in double quotes, i.e. `find "Test"`.

Comment: The responce now is: : >>> /system/bin/sh: find: not found output error.

Comment: You may have to use the full path to it, see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657872/windows-7-batch-find-i)